# Why this doesn't work in c++ constructors

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, destructor

I am trying to refresh my c++ so I decided to write a class with all the constructors but then I realised that it is not possible to reuse previously defined constructors(e.g. :this(arg1,arg2){} like c#).

So I tried this where the first is the header file and the second is the implementation file:

Header file:

```
class Point
{
public:
       int get_x() const;
       void set_x(int);

       int get_y() const;
       void set_y(int);

       Point(int, int);
       Point();
       Point(const Point&);
       ~Point();
private:
        int x_coord, y_coord;

};
```

Implementation file:

```
int Point::get_x() const
{
    return this->x_coord;
}
void Point::set_x(int x)
{
     this->x_coord = x;
}

int Point::get_y() const
{
    return this->y_coord;
}
void Point::set_y(int y)
{
     this->y_coord = y;
}

Point::Point(int x, int y)
{
  this->set_x(x);
  this->set_y(y);
}

Point::Point(const Point& p)
{
  Point(p.get_x(), p.get_y());
}

// class constructor
Point::Point()
{
  Point(0, 0);
}

// class destructor
Point::~Point()
{
    // insert your code here
}
```

And then in the main.cpp I do this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    Point a = Point(2, 3);
    Point b = Point(); 
    Point c = Point(a);

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Where only the 'a' object gets initialized correctly but the other two have these random values and don't get initialized the way I want them to be.

Comment: Your default and copy constructor are not initializing any of the data members. They are creating local, anonymous instances of `Point`.

Comment: C++11 gives you the ability to have delegating constructors: time to update your compiler.

Comment: @juanchopanza So, I have to do the very same thing (this->x = ..) on both places, no matter that I already have definition for such a context of initialization?

Comment: @user2128702, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555024/why-this-doesnt-work-in-c-constructors#comment38029941_24555024. Also, you should be using a constructor initializer list anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this constructor

```
Point::Point()
{
  Point(0, 0);
}
```

expression statement

```
  Point(0, 0);
```

creates a temporary object of type Point and deletes it at once. So the data members of the original object will not be initialized.

There is the same problem with the copy constructor

```
Point::Point(const Point& p)
{
  Point(p.get_x(), p.get_y());
}
```

What you want is the following

```
Point::Point(int x, int y) : x_coord( x ), y_coord( y )
{
}

Point::Point(const Point& p) : x_coord( p.x_coord ), y_coord( p.y_coord )
{
}

// class constructor
Point::Point() : Point( 0, 0 )
{
}
```

The last constructor is the same constructor as in C# that uses delegating only there is used the class name for naming the constructor instead of the keyword this.

Take into account that instead of

```
Point a = Point(2, 3);
Point b = Point(); 
Point c = Point(a);
```

it would be better and simpler to write

```
Point a(2, 3);
Point b; 
Point c = a;
```

Comment: The first two constructors work well, but the last one fails. It gives me the error: type 'class Point' is not a direct base of 'Point'.

Answer (score 3):

These two lines

```
Point(p.get_x(), p.get_y());
```

and

```
Point(0, 0);
```

do not do what you think they do: rather than invoking the corresponding constructor on the object being initialized, they create a new, unrelated temporary object, which gets discarded right away. The members of the `Point` being created remain uninitialized.

You could fix this by defining a private function that does initialization. If you have access to a modern C++ compiler, you could also use C++11 standard: which allows you to ["chain" constructors](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#delegating-ctor).

Answer (score 1):

```
Point::Point(const Point& p)
:  Point(p.get_x(), p.get_y())
{
}

Point::Point() 
: Point(0, 0)
{

}
```

Those are the constructors you would want to use.
This way you are calling the other constructor in what is called an initialiser list.

Your previous solutions just create a locale unnamed Point object, as calling Point() in a normal scope creates a Point object for you.

Secondly, you cannot use the `this` pointer safely within class construction, as the class has not been initialised fully yet, this means you will want to just refer to your types in the `get` and `set` methods by their names, not with `this->`. So for example:

```
int Point::get_x() const
{
    return this->x_coord;
}
```

becomes

```
int Point::get_x() const
{
    return x_coord;
}
```

On a side note and for a little more info - that `Point::Point(const Point& p)` constructor is known as a copy constructor and is used when using the `=` operator. In the case of below:

```
Point a;
Point b = a;
```

The above code will call your `Point::Point(const Point& p)` constructor.

Comment: I would reckon it is because of the use of the `this` pointer in your methods. Using the this pointer to access methods in a constructor is not usually performed in c++ and produces undefined behaviour. I've edited my answer to explain that.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Point::Point() : x_coord(0), y_coord(0) {}
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short / only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use a initializer list or have a common initialization function called from each constructor:

```
//initializer list
Point::Point() : x_coord(0), y_coord(0) {}
//common init function (call from constructors)
Point::init(int x, int y) { //perform initialization }
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to use default values in the default constructor as

```
Point::Point ( int x = 0, int y = 0 )
    : x_coord ( x ), y_coord ( y )
{}
```